# Azure Function is continuing to execute despite being disabled

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions

Like the title says I have an Azure function 'weekly_monitoring' which is set to execute multiple python scripts on a weekly basis. It is continuing to execute despite being disabled. Furthermore, it's executing multiple times in a row. I have no idea how this is possible as I have disabled the function via the UI as well as in the trigger (cron timer). Also, when I look at the Azure function monitor it shows zero execution activity.

Here is the init file code:

```
import azure.functions as func
import os
import datetime
import logging
import sys
import importlib.util

# Azure function timer. To alter timer cadence see function.json file
def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
    
    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)


def run_script(script_name):
    script_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), f'{script_name}')

    s = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(script_name, script_path)
    m = importlib.util.module_from_spec(s)
    sys.modules[s.name] = m
    s.loader.exec_module(m)

    
def batch_execution(file_list):

     exceptions = [] #store errors

     for file in file_list:
         try:
             run_script(file)
         except Exception as e:
             exceptions.append(e)
         else: 
             print('Success')

     return exceptions

# list of scripts running in function, if adding new script add to list.
 file_list = ['file_one.py',
         'file_two.py',
         'file_three.py',
         'file_four.py',
         'file_five.py']

batch_execution(file_list)
```

Here is the code to the trigger function:

```
{
    "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
    "bindings": [
      {
        "name": "mytimer",
        "type": "timerTrigger",
        "useMonitor": true,
        "runOnStartup": false,
        "direction": "in",
        "schedule": "0 5 * * MON"
      }
    ],
    "disabled": true
  }
```

[image: screen shot of the disables function in the Azure UI]

[image: Number of functions invocations according to Azure Monitor, I have the script has executed 5 times today]

Comment: Can you share how you know, despite the evidence you’ve presented here, that the function is still being triggered? Is it possible the code has been configured in another function or piece of infrastructure that you don’t have access to or awareness of?

Comment: @esqew The scripts executed in the init file deliver an automated email via Spark Post. So the emails are showing up for me daily even though its disabled, there is seemingly no azure activity, and the cron timer is set to weekly.

Comment: Is it possible the emails are being delivered posthumously after being trapped somewhere? Does Spark Post provide any information about the origin of the messages themselves within their toolset?

Comment: @esqew ah yes I can see the emails sending in SparkPost History. Unsure how they are stuck in spark post but that is likely the issue and not azure. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discovered in the comments on the OP, it seems the messages spawned by previous executions of the Azure Function (pre-disabling) seem to be stuck in the intermediary email provider and are being delivered posthumously.